# Fancytree checkboxes

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, fancytree

Is there a way to make fancytree checkboxes match the containing form checkboxes?

For example, in the example form http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/demo/#sample-form.html, the checkboxes in the checkbox section and the checkboxes in the select sections contain fancytree checkboxes that do not match in style.

I am using bootstrap, and do not want to use glyphs, but still just want the fancytree checkboxes to match the form-control style of checkbox.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fancytree uses images instead of native checkboxes (i.e. `<input type="checkbox">`), mainly because this allows to implement tri-state modes. The glyph extension enables glyph fonts instead of images, which doesn't help in your case.
There is currently no switch to use native checkboxes, though you might try to implement it using rendering in the `createNode` or `renderNode` callback.

Comment: thanks, this is what i thought but just checking I hadn't missed something obvious.

Comment: `<input type="checkbox">` supports tri-state modes: [indeterminate](https://css-tricks.com/indeterminate-checkboxes/).